# LinkedIn post embed in iFrame blocked by CSP on iOS / Capacitor app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, embed, content-security-policy, capacitor

I want to embed a LinkedIn post in a capacitor app.

It works fine on Android, but on iOS it doesn't load, and I get the following error:

`Refused to load https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6898694772484112384 because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.`

Right now I am just using

`<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6898694772484112384" />`

Instagram posts embedded in the same way are working fine. Only LinkedIn is not loading.

I tried setting sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" on the iframe, but it doesn't help.

There is no Content-Security-Policy on my side. I then tried to add a CSP allowing linkedin.com (or just everything *) in the index.html of the capacitor app but that didn't fix it either.

I also tried to allow linkedin.com in the capacitor config..

```
"server": {
      "allowNavigation": [
          "*",
          "linkedin.com"
      ]
```

That didn't help either.